# Chrome on Mac crashes when unicode content w/ specific CSS property

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here's a quick demo. I crash my **Chrome** on Mac OS every time when I hit the button.

```
$('#foo').html('\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c\u89ba\u5f97\u5f88\u6eff\u610f\u2764\ufe0f\uff0c\u4e00\u5b9a\u8981\u7167\u76d2\u5b50\u4e0a\u9762\u7684\u8aaa\u660e\u9000\u51b0\u518d\u5403\uff0c\u53e3\u611f\u624d\u525b\u525b\u597d\r\n');
```

Be careful. It crashes the tab after you hit the button.
http://jsfiddle.net/scdwL9na/5/

Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)

Comment: Same version of Chrome here on OSX 10.10.2, could not reproduce

Comment: Sounds more like a bug report you should post to the Chromium folks rather than a question for SO.

Comment: Won't crash for me. Actually that function will display some chinese-like characters. Maybe your browser has a "soft-spot" when it comes to Chinese symbols.